# Twilio - How to check if the gathered speech results having expected values if not mark it as failed

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

Need help in validation of the speechresults: I am trying to validating if we are getting correct speech results in the twiml function. I am able to fetch the speech results and perform certain action on them.. but I want to fail my test when it is not matching. How to achieve this.. Thanks in advance. My sample code

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) 
{
     let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
     console.log("Event = " + JSON.stringify(event));
     let ivrSpeech = (event.SpeechResult ? event.SpeechResult : "").toLowerCase();
     let servicetype = event.servicetype;
     console.log("Call type" + servicetype);
     let IVRType = event.ivrgoal;
    if (ivrSpeech && ivrSpeech.length > 0)
        {
             if(servicetype.includes("XX")) 
                {
                  if (ivrSpeech.includes("Call may be recorded and monitored for quality purpose"))
                        {
                             twiml.pause({ length: 10 });
                           
                        }
                   else 
                        {
                         XXX - fail my test 
                        }

                 }
         }
   callback(null, twiml)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First, you have one issue with your code that means you will always fail the check.

When you get the `ivrSpeech` you call `.toLowerCase()` on it:

```js
     let ivrSpeech = (event.SpeechResult ? event.SpeechResult : "").toLowerCase();
```

But then you test against a string with a capital letter in it:

```js
if (ivrSpeech.includes("Call may be recorded and monitored for quality purpose"))
```

So you should change that to start with.

Otherwise, I am not sure what you mean when you say you want to "fail my test" when it doesn't match. You have the code written out pretty well so far, but I don't quite understand what you want to do in the `else` condition.

One option is to hang up the call, which you would achieve like this:

```js
    if (ivrSpeech && ivrSpeech.length > 0)
        {
             if(servicetype.includes("XX")) 
                {
                  if (ivrSpeech.includes("call may be recorded and monitored for quality purpose"))
                        {
                             twiml.pause({ length: 10 });
                           
                        }
                   else 
                        {
                             twiml.hangup();
                        }

                 }
         }
   callback(null, twiml)
```